# How to create minimum size (empty) zip file, which has 22B?

Tags: linux, windows, compression, zip

I´m trying to solve some security problem with file, whose MD5 hash is 76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c.

I don't have that file, but based on internet MD5 searches, I think, it is minimum size zip file.
I found one [example](http://data.ottawa.ca/nl/dataset/recreation-guides/resource/8811dcb4-8aab-46c3-8b2f-33d0ee456ce2) and its content is exactly same like [minimum size zip file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Limits).

**Is it possible to create such minimum size zip file (22 B)  with Linux (or Windows) command?**

BTW: Recently, I solved similar task with gzip file: `gzip -n EmptyFileName`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Here you go:

```
50 4b 05 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00
```

That has the MD5 signature you provided.

If you have Info-ZIP's zip, you can create it thusly:

```
zip empty.zip anyfile
zip -d empty.zip anyfile
```

That adds "anyfile" to a new zip file, and then deletes it from the zip file, leaving it empty.

Comment: Arguably, directly echoing the bytes to a file is a simpler method of creation:  `echo -n '\x50\x4b\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' > empty.zip`

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi It works with zsh. With bash or sh, you have to add the `-e` option: `echo -ne '\x50\x4b\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' > empty.zip`

Answer (score 13):

An easier-to-use version for copying-and-pasting into the shell:

```bash
echo UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA== | base64 -d > empty.zip
```

This just prints the `base64`'d version of the empty zip file (created by creating a zip file with a single file then deleting that single file from the zip file), and reverse the encoding with `base64 -d` and writes the output to `empty.zip`.

---

If the version of `base64` that ships with your machine doesn't use the same syntax as above, here's a more-portable but less-terse alternative:

```bash
echo UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==  | openssl enc -d -base64 > empty.zip
```

Comment: I had to use `-D` instead of `-d` on my system. You can use `echo -n` to avoid the newline, however you don't need to. Just use `echo`. `base64` doesn't care about the newline.

Comment: @MarkAdler Thanks. `echo -n` isn't portable, but I completely forgot that `base64` doesn't care about line endings. I'm not sure what's the most portable way of doing base64 decode, perhaps via `openssl` but that's not available oob on macOS any longer, I think.

Comment: I have the latest macOS, and the openssl command from LibreSSL 2.2.7 is there. It also has base64.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkAdler; added an openssl-based variant to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

With Info-Zip (standard zip/unzip installation on Ubuntu 20.04), you will have to use the `-i "*"` option. If it's not present, zip will complain and exit with error code 1 on creation. Counter-intuitively, its behaviour changes with `-i "*"`.

```
mkdir /tmp/mytest
cd /tmp/mytest
zip -r mytest.zip . -i "*"
```

`mytest.zip` will be the empty zip file you desire.

Answer (score 1):

with this `.bat` script you can create `empty.zip` file under windows:

```
@echo off

del /q /f empty.zip >nul 2>nul
certutil -decode "%~f0" empty.zip

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 0):

### tldr;

#### use `printf`

```
$ printf '\x50\x4b\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' >empty.zip
$ md5sum empty.zip 
76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c  empty.zip
```

#### use `base64`

```
$ base64 -d >empty.zip <<'EOF'
UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
EOF
$ md5sum empty.zip
76cdb2bad9582d23c1f6f4d868218d6c  empty.zip
```

### Explanation

While the `zip` tool doesn't support the creation of an empty zip file, you can create a non-empty zip file and then remove its contents:

```
$ touch foo.txt
$ zip empty.zip foo.txt
  adding: foo.txt (stored 0%)
$ zip -d empty.zip foo.txt
deleting: foo.txt
    zip warning: zip file empty
```

Note how `zipinfo` returns an error when given the resulting `empty.zip`:

```
$ zipinfo empty.zip 
Archive:  empty.zip
Zip file size: 22 bytes, number of entries: 0
Empty zipfile.
$ echo $?
1
```

You can confirm that `empty.zip` has the expected bytes:

```
$ file empty.zip
empty.zip: Zip archive data (empty)
$ xxd empty.zip
00000000: 504b 0506 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  PK..............
00000010: 0000 0000 0000                           ......
```

You can use `printf` to write those 22 bytes (in hexadecimal) directly into a file:

```
$ printf '\x50\x4b\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' >empty.zip
```

You can also turn those 22 bytes into 32 base64-encoded characters and use that:

```
$ base64 <empty.zip 
UEsFBgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```